# How can I add video effects like these to my video

Tags: video

I want to add a beginning like in this video

Which software should I use?

I am completely clueless. Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everyone's clueless when they start. Dive in :)

I reckon this was made with [Adobe After Effects](https://www.adobe.com/uk/products/aftereffects.html).
It's a combination of shapes, masks, and text animating on, with lots of easing and bouncing on the movement.

This is a great but old free tutorial on the basics of after effects:
https://www.videocopilot.net/basic/

The easing and bouncing might have been done manually, but more likely using something like the [Mt MoGraph Motion](https://www.mtmograph.com/products/motion-3) plugin.

Comment: There's nothing in this intro which requires After Effects, specifically, and plenty of alternatives are available.  Apple Motion is an easy one if you're on a Mac.  BlackMagic Fusion is less easy, but cross-platform, including Linux, and there's a free version.

Comment: The question was "which should I use".. Which is personal preference at the end of the day.. If you have useful links for the poster to follow based on those packages, please add them as another answer.

Comment: No, the question was "How can I.."  if it were "which should I use," I would've flagged it for being opinion-based.  Your answer expresses an unsolicited personal opinion.  A better answer would not.

Comment: Please add your better answer.  I wish you well.

Comment: I am so happy that you answered my naive question.